# fullscreen is not working after a breakpoint in firefox debugger or after a call to the alert function

Tags: javascript, firefox, fullscreen

Example of Javascript function:

```
function openFullscreen() {
   alert ("Full Screen Active!");
   if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
     elem.requestFullscreen();
   } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
     elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
   } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari & Opera */
     elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
   } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
     elem.msRequestFullscreen();
   }
}
```

It works with the Edge browser or if the alert function is omitted. Same problem, if a breakpoint is set at the beginning of the routine.

Also noted that the following example works with Edge but not with Firefox:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_fullscreen2

Can someone tell me why this is so or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's the browser default behavior. It's caused because the browser window has lost its focus. If the browser is on full-screen but it loses focus, it will revert back to the original screen state. You should console log your stuff to debug

Comment: Actually the browser window is never on full-screen. I think the debugger or the alert function controls the window and gives the control back when finished. Only then is requestFullscreen called. However the window handler seems still to be in the state where it refuses the call to full screen. Seems to be a problem of priorities. Anyway, thanks for the prompt answer.